# Can I install LAMP over existing Apache installation?

Tags: software-installation, apache-httpd

I'm setting up my first VPS, and I installed and configured Apache before I realized that there was the LAMP package to do that for me. Can I run `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` or do I have to uninstall the existing Apache first?

Comment: It's the way to install LAMP per the Ubuntu help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It won't override your current Apache installation. When you type `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` it just selects the packages included in a task called "lamp-server" and install them:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-mpm-prefork libaio1
  libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl
  libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 php5-cli php5-common
  php5-json php5-mysql php5-readline
```

So, there's nothing to worry about. Now, if you install LAMP using other method, ie. downloading some kind of package and executing an script, in that case, yes, you will have problems.

Comment: Thanks very much. You'd think this would be a common question (well, maybe not that common, but common enough), but I couldn't find an answer anywhere. If I was more familiar with apt-get then maybe it would have been obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can both install the lamp-server package over the apache2, or uninstall apache2 before that:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

Don't worry, you'll not break anything anyway :)